# Symfony: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony2 __construct, my code is

```
public function __construct() {
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    }

Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in F:\xampp\htdocs\Salon\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php line 208
```

Please Help me,Thx~

Comment: Could we get a bit more code so we can see if there's problems elsewhere. I would guess that there may be a problem in the `getSession()` function

Comment: This is a controller right?  Don't put stuff in a controller's __construct unless you really know what your doing.  The request is not available from the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `$this->getRequest()` is just a shortcut method for `$this->container->get('request')` of the basic controller. Essentially, you are calling the container to get you the `Request` object. However, the container in not available in the basic controller's constructor. If you really need the `Request` object in your controller's constructor, you could make it a service and inject the request into it.

Comment: Thx you help me. I want use inject~ :)